# Magento 2 - Categories dissapear from the left side

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, contact-us

I add a block the Contact page in the left side, when the page appear the categories are there then disappear instant.

I add this in my theme Magento_Contact/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class='Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm' name="contact_categories" as="contact_categories" template="Magento_Contact::categories.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

and here is my function:

```
function categoryLoop($id, $is_sub = false){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
if($categories->hasChildren()){
echo '<ul' . (($is_sub) ? ' class="category_children category-'.$categories->getId().'"' : '') . '>';
        $subcategories = explode(',', $categories->getChildren());
        foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
            $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
              echo '<li><a href="'.$subcategory->getUrl().'">';
            echo $subcategory->getName();
            echo "</a></li>";
            if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category, true); }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Where is the problem with this code?

Update:

I found something strange in the console, there is loading this link:

```
curl 'http://example.com/page_cache/block/render/id/85/?blocks=%5B%22contact_categories%22%5D&handles=%5B%22default%22%2C%22catalog_category_view%22%2C%22catalog_category_view_type_default%22%2C%22catalog_category_view_id_85%22%5D&originalRequest=%7B%22route%22%3A%22catalog%22%2C%22controller%22%3A%22category%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22uri%22%3A%22%2Fpriming.html.html%22%7D&version=d3dea50753cd897b6f6b4f7a47549f6d' -H 'Host: qpaints.edreamag.co' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: http://example.com/priming.html.html' -H 'Cookie: store=default; mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; form_key=9t3LSEkpkUjYf4bQ; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; product_data_storage=%7B%7D; section_data_ids=%7B%22cart%22%3A1508761022%2C%22customer%22%3A1508761022%2C%22compare-products%22%3A1508761022%2C%22last-ordered-items%22%3A1508761022%2C%22directory-data%22%3A1508761022%2C%22wishlist%22%3A1508761022%2C%22recently_viewed_product%22%3A1508761022%2C%22recently_compared_product%22%3A1508761022%2C%22product_data_storage%22%3A1508761022%2C%22paypal-billing-agreement%22%3A1508761022%7D; private_content_version=d3dea50753cd897b6f6b4f7a47549f6d; PHPSESSID=770b4c79f687007539699ef59cda09f5; mage-cache-sessid=true'
```

and after this the categories dissapear.

Thank you

Comment: Show me full categories.phtml, please

Comment: that is the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier you can use standard block class **\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu** for output tree of directories.

Example usage:

> your_theme_root/Magento_Theme/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" template="Magento_Theme::sidebar_categories.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> your_theme_root/Magento_Theme/templates/sidebar_categories.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Categories on sidebar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>
<ul>
    <?= $block->getHtml() ?>
</ul>
```

Dont't forget clear cache. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but is the same, this module disappear too

Comment: Try disable full page caching on admin page `System -> Cache Management`. Issue is repeated?

Comment: indeed with cache disabled the issue is fixed ...

Comment: so what can be solution for this? you have any idea?

Comment: You are sure refreshed all cache? On my environment with FPC it working good

Comment: on my with cache enabled that categories dissapear for that I post here ...